# Jquery, for loop shows all

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, checkbox

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    var pp = []
    var ing = []

    for (var q = 1; q <= 6; q++) {
        pp[q - 1] = $('input[name=P' + (q) + ']').is(":checked");
        ing[q - 1] = $('div#ingp' + (q) + '').show();
    }

    for (var q = 1; q <= 6; q++) {
        if (pp[q - 1] == true) {
            ing[q - 1];
        }
    }
});
```

```
<div class="Pizzas container" id="checkbox_pizza">
    <h1>Kies uw Pizza.</h1>
    <form id="Pi">
        <input type="checkbox" name="P1" id="g"> &euro;6,00 -Margherita (Kaas en tomaten)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="P2" id="h"> &euro;7,20 -Napolitana (tomaten, kaas, kappertjes, ansjovis)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="P3" id="i"> &euro;7,50 -Salami (kaas, tomaten en salami)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="P4" id="j"> &euro;7,50 -Prosciutto (tomaten, kaas, ham)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="P5" id="k"> &euro;7,00 -Funghi (tomaten, kaas, champions)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="P6" id="l"> &euro;8,00 -Tonno (tomaten, kaas, tonijn, ui)
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="knop" value="button" />
    </form>
</div>

<div class="container" id="Boxx">
    <div id="ingrediënten">
        <div>
            <h1>Kies extra ingredienten</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="ingp1"></div>
        <div id="ingp2"></div>
        <div id="ingp3"></div>
        <div id="ingp4"></div>
        <div id="ingp5"></div>
        <div id="ingp6"></div>
        <input type="button" id="knop2" value="Totaal" />
    </div>
</div>
```

So the problem I have is that when I look if one or more of `P1` to `P6` is check then it shows all 6 div with id `ingp1` to `ingp6`.
I want it to show `ingp1` when `P1` is checked, and `ingp3` when `P3` is checked. You get it.
How do I do this (small thing I am only allowed to use javascript and jquery).

Comment: Using incremental ids is an anti-pattern as you end up tying yourself in knots, and it's a nightmare to maintain. Use common classes and DOM traversal instead. To guide you how to do that we would need to see your HTML.

Comment: Let me see if I understood you right: Every checkbox has a correlation with a div? For instance: clicking on checkbox 1 only displays div 1 and so forth? Does it rely on a button to trigger the desired result or on the checkbox?

Comment: @n0m4d When you press the button it checks what checkboxes are checked, Then it needs to show the div that is matched with that checkbox so checkbox 1 with div 1. Thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add a common class names for the elements in the form and the div's in the container as I have given test1,test2 etc.

```js
$('document').ready(function() { 
    var test
 $("#Pi input[ type = 'checkbox']").click(function() { 
  var test = this.className
  if ( this.checked == true )
  {
     $('#ingredienten .'+test).show()
           console.log($('#ingrediënten .'+test))
  } 
  else
  {
   $('#ingrediënten .'+test).hide()
  }
 })
 })
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"   integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="Pizzas container" id="checkbox_pizza">
    <h1>Kies uw Pizza.</h1>
    <form id="Pi">
        <input type="checkbox" class = "test1" name="P1" id="g"> &euro;6,00 -Margherita (Kaas en tomaten)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class = "test2" name="P2" id="h"> &euro;7,20 -Napolitana (tomaten, kaas, kappertjes, ansjovis)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class = "test3" name="P3" id="i"> &euro;7,50 -Salami (kaas, tomaten en salami)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class = "test4" name="P4" id="j"> &euro;7,50 -Prosciutto (tomaten, kaas, ham)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class = "test5" name="P5" id="k"> &euro;7,00 -Funghi (tomaten, kaas, champions)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class = "test6" name="P6" id="l"> &euro;8,00 -Tonno (tomaten, kaas, tonijn, ui)
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="knop" value="button" />
    </form>
</div>

<div class="container" id="Boxx">
    <div id="ingredienten">
        <div>
            <h1>Kies extra ingredienten</h1></div>
        <div id="ingp1" class = "test1">

        </div>
        <div id="ingp2" class = "test2">

        </div>
        <div id="ingp3" class = "test3">

        </div>
        <div id="ingp4" class = "test4">

        </div>
        <div id="ingp5" class = "test5">

        </div>
        <div id="ingp6" class = "test6">

        </div>
        <input type="button" id="knop2" value="Totaal" />
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
  <html>
```

Then take the class name of the clicked check-box and search the div with  the class name of this check-box and show or hide the div depending on its checked property.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 for (var q = 1; q <= 6; q++) 
 {
    if ( $( 'input[ name = "P' + q + '"]').is(":checked") )
    {
       $( 'div#ingp' + q ).show();
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $('input[name^=P]').each(function () {
        var idx = this.name.replace('P', '');
        $('div#ingp' + idx).toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

In words

- for each `<input>` whose `name` starts with `'P'`,
- find the associated `<div>` with the proper ID
- toggle its visibility based on whether the `<input>` is checked or not

Comment: I used it but I didnt get me any outcome, All I got was a blank page. Could you explain how the part with finding the <div> witht he proper ID works in this function.

Comment: The button in your sample code does not have the ID "button", it has the ID "knop", that's why the code above does not seem to do anything. I'm not going to explain the code any further, sorry. It's only four lines and it's really obvious what it does and how it does it. If you can't see it, go though it line by line and find out. You are here to learn, after all, not to copy and paste. At least I hope that's the case. ;) Working sample in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3sbd8upc/

Answer (score 0):

@Ttech thanks for clarifying the SO to me. Here's my solution. I slightly changed the markup in the part concerning the ids of the extra ingredients section (the divs).

Please, check my working example and see if this is what you need.

```js
$('#ingrediënten div').hide();

$('#knop').on('click', function() {
 
  $('#ingrediënten div').hide();

  var $checkedOptions = $('#Pi input[type=checkbox]').filter(':checked'),
    $extraIngredients = $('#ingrediënten div');

  $checkedOptions.each(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('name');
    
    $extraIngredients.filter('[id=' + id + ']').show();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Pizzas container" id="checkbox_pizza">
  <h1>Kies uw Pizza.</h1>
  <form id="Pi">
    <input type="checkbox" name="P1" id="g"> &euro;6,00 -Margherita (Kaas en tomaten)
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="P2" id="h"> &euro;7,20 -Napolitana (tomaten, kaas, kappertjes, ansjovis)
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="P3" id="i"> &euro;7,50 -Salami (kaas, tomaten en salami)
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="P4" id="j"> &euro;7,50 -Prosciutto (tomaten, kaas, ham)
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="P5" id="k"> &euro;7,00 -Funghi (tomaten, kaas, champions)
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="P6" id="l"> &euro;8,00 -Tonno (tomaten, kaas, tonijn, ui)
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="knop" value="button" />
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container" id="Boxx">
  <div id="ingrediënten">
    <div>
      <h1>Kies extra ingredienten</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="P1">
      Extra ingredient 1
    </div>
    <div id="P2">
      Extra ingredient 2
    </div>
    <div id="P3">
      Extra ingredient 3
    </div>
    <div id="P4">
      Extra ingredient 4
    </div>
    <div id="P5">
      Extra ingredient 5
    </div>
    <div id="P6">
      Extra ingredient 6
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="knop2" value="Totaal" />
  </div>
</div>
```